# The changes of the "Affected pages" in Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

I occasionally check the list of URLs that is "not indexed" and "indexed" for my own websites in Google Search Console.

While it is useful to know what URLs/pages Google don't like, it's not easy (as long as I know) to know what pages Google started to not like (because the dashboard doesn't provide the diffs), didn't like (because the dashboard doesn't provide the change history).

So, is there any feature or way to check the changes/diffs of the index/not-indexed/affected-pages URL list in Google Search Console?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only solution is to export the data from Google Search Console and run a diff on the two lists. There might be tools around that integrate with Google Search Console and do the job for you, however the task is trivial and so I would just do it myself from time to time. The benefit of doing it on my own is also that I get an exact diff between now and the last export, where tools might give you a diff on a schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Looker Studio would be my recommendation. You can connect to your GSC properties there just like you would Google Analytics.

With it's built in functionality, you can have it calculate diffs automatically for every page that appears there. So no more manual calculations and you have it at a click of a link.

It would also be handy in figuring out what page/search term combos are seeing the biggest change.

As far as the index/noindex, I don't know if there is a dimension in there specifically for that. So that analysis might still need to be done manually.